# Storing arrays with Wordpress Settings API has strange behaviour

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the Wordpress Settings API for storing some settings for my plugin. The user can put some information about a flat (like size, level, etc.).
In my settings sanitize callback I want to create an array, because the user can store multiple flats.
Here is my callback function. If the option doesn't exist yet a new array is created. If it is already there the new flat is appended to the array.

```
  public function flatSanitize($input) {

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($input);
    echo '</pre>';

    $output = get_option('flat_option');

    if ( !$output ) {
      $output = array(
        $input
      );
      echo '<br><pre>';
      var_dump($output);
      echo '</pre>';
      die();
      return $output;
    }


    $output[] = array($input);
    return $output;
  }
```

The output of this script is correct:

Input:

```
array(5) {
  ["squaremeter"]=> string(2) "50"
  ["level"] => string(9) "1st floor"
}
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
      array(5) {
          ["squaremeter"] => string(2) "50"
          ["level"]=> string(9) "1st floor"
      }
}
```

But if I put the option in the database and query it later via get_option('flat_option'), this is what I get:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
      array(5) {
          ["squaremeter"] => string(2) "50"
          ["level"]=> string(9) "1st floor"
      }
  }
}
```

As you can see it is always putting another level in the array. I cannot control this behaviour. For another option it is always putting it into another array again and using an empty "" key for this array like so:

```
array(1) {
  "" =>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
      array(5) {
          ["squaremeter"] => string(2) "50"
          ["level"]=> string(9) "1st floor"
      }
  }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it would be useful to see your update_option function call. Do you have probably something like this in there? `update_option('flat_option', [$input]);` ?

It would also be good to know how you query and output the option later on.

Comment: There is no direct call to update_option from me. This is all handled by the wordpress settings API. You just have this sanitize callback where you can sanitize the input data and return it from the callback.
The query later for the option is done via get_option('flat_option') and I just use var_dump for echoing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem.
In your plugin activate routine, you should initialize your options with a default value of an empty array to which you can append your values later:

```
    if ( ! get_option( 'flat_options' ) ) {
        update_option( 'flat_options', array() );
    }
```

Then in your sanitize callback you can check the count of the array and append to the array:

```
if (count($output) == 0 ) {
  $output[] = $input;
  return $output;
}
```